# How to acess the return values from one function to other function using python3?

Tags: python-3.x, function

How to acess the return values from one function to other function using python3? I cannot able to pass the return function from one function to other?
I am new to programming please help me

```
import os
import sys
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image 
from pdf2image import convert_from_path 


filename = "C:\\Users\\subashini.u\\Desktop\\tesseract-python\\penang_40.2.pdf"

def tesseract(filename): 
    PDF_file = filename 
    pages = convert_from_path(PDF_file, 500)  
    image_counter = 1

    for page in pages:  
        filename = "page_"+str(image_counter)+".jpg"
        page.save(filename, 'JPEG') 
        image_counter = image_counter + 1

    filelimit = image_counter-1
    outfile = "C:\\Users\\subashini.u\\Desktop\\tesseract-python\\text_file.txt"
    f = open(outfile, "a",encoding = "utf-8") 

    for i in range(1, filelimit + 1): 
        filename = "page_"+str(i)+".jpg"
        text = str(((pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))))) 
        text = text.replace('-\n', '')     
        #print(text)
        f.write(text) 

    f.close() 
    f1 = open(outfile, "r",encoding = "utf-8") 
    input_file = f1.readlines()
    return input_file


def a(input_file): 
    for i in input_file: # i want to acess the return value here 
        print(i)

a(input_file)
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve here, what is the expected output and what is the result that you are getting. I can see that what you have done is correct but I need to know more about the results to get to a conclusion.

Comment: You can do the same return from `a` which you did from `tesseract` @suba, check my answer below :)

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh thank you so much for taking time to solve my question. I want to directly use return value from that function...I changed my code please help me

Comment: Can you add comments where you are having problems, I cannot guess from your code what is it you want @suba ?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh i added the comment

Comment: i want to acess the return value here you mean return value from tesseract? I have updated my answer according to what I think is needed, please check @suba

Answer (score 0):

Just return from function `a` like you did for `tesseract` function, also you don't need `input_file` as an argument to `a`, since you get that from `tesseract` function

```
def a():
    #Pass filename to tesseract
    input_file = tesseract(filename)

    #Use returned value from tesseract here
    for i in input_file: 
        print(i)
```

A simpler example is below, where `func1` returns to `func2` and `func2` returns to `main`

```
def func1(a):

    #return value from func1
    return a

def func2(b):

    #Get return value from func1
    x = func1(b)

    #Return value from func2
    return x

print(func2(3))
```

The output will be

```
3
```